# Any NVidia driver install breaks 19.04

Tags: nvidia, 19.04

So... Ubuntu will not co-operate with me.
Doing my first install of 19.04 and if I download the 390 NVidia driver from anywhere, the ppa, software update or during the install, the system will not boot afterwards. It either hangs on a NVidia Daemon or starting GDM, but I’m not being specific as every time I have to reinstall and try the next option as GRUB2 will not show upon hold ESC, Shift or C.
As a I have said, I have used the PPA and the properiatary drivers, and nothing works.
CPU: Intel i5 2410M
GFX: NVidia 520M
Driver: Whatever the latest version of 390 for Ubuntu is.

Comment: Which PPA? or which ppas? Could you switch and use a text terminal?  where they are clues in the logs as to problems?  Details are necessary in order to help you (eg. `apt-cache policy` details so we know exactly what you tried), even specific detail as to what video card you have `sudo lshw -C video` for example (as seen by chips on board/computer, not marketing hype intended to sell item).

Comment: for me I need to replace in /booty/grub/grub.cfg the two timeout=0 with timeout=10 . and apart from updates changing it back again, I caught it doing that last night because this laptop ran out of power and closed down.                                     ..as for the drivers, I need to delete /lib/firmware/amdgpu/raven_dmcu.bin     to get other than the blank screen, I had some success with the latest kernel manually updating it, but, alas, there were too many graphics problems with it for now. Ubuntu 19.04. Ryzen 2500U .

Answer (score 0):

I just installed 18.04 and the drivers worked fine. Thanks for your replies though!